# docker cannot connect to redis from file

Tags: python, docker, redis, docker-compose

I am running docker using docker-compose up.

In a file I am trying to access the redis created using:

```
import redis

pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
r.flushall()
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml redis portion:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
  links:
   - db
   - redis
  environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:openhouse2016@db:5432/chat
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/1
  volumes:
    - .:/opt/app
db:
  image: praiskup/postgresql:APIv1.0.1-fedora23
#  volumes:
#   - ./db:/var/lib/pgsql/data
  environment:
   - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=chat
   - POSTGRESQL_USER=user
   - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=openhouse2016
   - POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER_OPTS=assert_external_data = false
worker:
  build: .
  environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:openhouse2016@db:5432/chat
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/1
  links:
   - db
   - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/opt/app
  # we need to wait for database setup
  command: bash -c "sleep 7 && exec python /opt/app/channels-example/manage.py runworker -v3"
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
        - "6379:6379"
migrator:
  build: .
  environment:
   - DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:openhouse2016@db:5432/chat
   - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/1
  links:
   - db
  # it indeed takes this long to start the database
  command: bash -c "sleep 5 && exec python /opt/app/channels-example/manage.py migrate"
```

After running:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Everything runs fine and redis says it is ready to accept connections on port 6379.

However, the python code above generates:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -5 connecting to redis:6379. No address associated with hostname.
```

How do I connect to redis from the python file?

EDIT:

```
docker ps -a
```

redis shows:

```
3a494c9da73d     redis        "docker-entrypoint.sh" 
10 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds  0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
```

Comment: What happens when you run a docker ps? Is everything running on the right port? Does it show the right mapping? Can you reach the service via the appropriate url and port from the machine you are using?

Comment: Yes it appears as if everything is in the right port. Added it in edit. However, I am trying to connect via "redis:6379" which may be incorrect. If I try "0.0.0.0:6379" I get "ECONNREFUSED" error.

Comment: You can't access a container by a hostname without modifications to your hosts file. And 0.0.0.0 is not the IP address of the container.

Comment: Is the python code also in a container, or running on your local machine?

Comment: Is this running on a Mac (with `docker-machine`?)

Comment: No, running on ubuntu. The python code is running in a container.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the definition of the container as it appears in your `docker-compose.yml`? Because I'm suspecting maybe you have to link the `redis` image (the `redis` docker) with the Python container using the `links:` section. Something like: `links: redis:redis`? (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links) However, I've been a bit out of touch with Docker, lately

Comment: Is that your full compose file?

Comment: No its not. I can post the full file if needed.

Comment: @shell That would help, yes.

Comment: Using my own compose file to bring up redis I'm really having no problems running your Python code. You did mention that you are setting up another container that is running that Python code. Did you ensure that you linked your containers to communicate with one another appropriately?

Comment: If the failure is in your `migrator`, you are not linking the `redis` container with it (in the `links:` section). If the failure is in your `worker`... Then I really don't know, because that one is linking it correctly (as far as I can see) **:-S**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migrator did not link to redis. This fixed it:

```
migrator:
  build: .
  environment:
   - DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:openhouse2016@db:5432/chat
   - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/1
  links:
   - db
   - redis #this line here was missing
  # it indeed takes this long to start the database
  command: bash -c "sleep 5 && exec python /opt/app/channels-example/manage.py migrate"
```